# Secret Token URL Placement

Tags: registration

I'm working on an application conceptually similar to a pastebin, only with tables. The user will fill out the table and then save it. He'll be redirected to a permanent URL, which he can then share with others so they can view his data as well. This is probably the most common use case, which is why I decided against user registration in the first place.

However, the user might want to come back to make small incremental changes to his data. So I thought it would be nice for him to have a second URL including a secret token, that would identify him as the original author. Now I'm conflicted as to where to put this second URL.

1. Make it the default redirection URL. Here he could easily bookmark the view, but might also accidentally give other's write access by sending them the URL.
2. Place it somewhere on the site. Probably preferable, but I'm a little concerned, the user will lose write access himself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How does Pastebin solve this problem? Do you need to register to have any edit rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) have a system that may be useful to you. It doesn't require registration or anything like that.

When you upload an image, you get shown a list of links to use:

[image]

That list of links provide different methods of sharing that asset, either the direct URL or the URL in a variety of formats for use on boards, websites, blogs etc.

So my suggestion is to do something like that. On creation and then 'Save' of the item you can provide the user with a variety of links to use. One can be the public 'share' option and another can be the 'edit' link.

OK, that does mean its up to the user themselves to copy and store that link incase they do wish to edit the item in future. But if they haven't registered then that's (possibly) a sacrifice that you're willing to offer. If they *are* registered then it's straight forward to give them access to this list of links when they choose the table they created from their own profile.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this. Any particular reason, you chose  to upload that image?

Comment: @hauptbenutzer: Haha, that's my default test image. It used to be a smiley face but I'd used that too often so it was getting confusing seeing it everywhere. So I grumpied him up a bit.